# Java Web Application Query Is Not Working

Tags: java, mysql

My program of java is connected to a database which has tables Asset_11398 and Emp_11398.. both are connected through a relationship..

i want to write a query which will should show the Assets which are not allocated to employees.. means it should only show the fields where the 'Emp_ID' field is empty..
i have been trying to run it using the query below but i know there is something wrong with it.. can someone please take a look at the query?

```
ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from Asset_11398 Where Emp_ID = null");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try something like this:

```
ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from Asset_11398 Where Emp_ID is NULL");
```

Comment: no.. it isnt working..

Comment: I have updated the code block. It should work. Just note that when query a Null col|row, there should use "is" not "="